# Using a custom control in Android Studio,it says "missing classes"

Tags: android

I use a custom control in Android Studio, it says "missing classes". But, I write the class that I need.Please help me, I would appreciate it very much.

Class code:

```
package cwing.study;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by asus on 2017/9/1.
 */

public class TitleLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public TitleLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.title,this);
    }
}
```

using class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="cwing.study.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/title"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
    <cwing.study.TitleLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm a newbie, so if the format is incorrect, please point out.

Comment: build the application first, then it will see the classes.

Comment: @VladMatvienko,thank you very much! It's so easy.